# Ghost parts are not visible when overlaying a ghost cube

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

I'm trying to create objects using an overlay manager.
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/OverlayManager/

I prepared a ghost cube that contains an overlay, but the ghost parts that overlap the overlay are not displayed.

I tried enabling depthWrite and depthTest for the material used for the overlay, and changing the renderOrder of the mesh, but it had no effect.

Is it because of the specifications that overlapping ghost members cannot be expressed?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly you try to achieve, perhaps including some screenshots as well? Also, it's not clear to me what you mean by "a ghost cube that contains an overlay". An overlay is just a scene that may include custom geometry. It is not possible to contain the overlay in another object.